# Selecionar registros por ordem

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo uma loja virtual do zero e o cliente pediu para eu fazer a seguinte lógica:

- Seleciona primeiros os produtos disponíveis com foto
- Seleciona depois os disponíveis sem foto
- Seleciona depois os indisponíveis com foto
- seleciona depois os indisponívels sem foto

O problema é que não tenho noção de como fazer isso, pois que eu saiba só da para realizar a seleção com o **where status = '1' AND foto != ''**, como posso fazer para seguir a ordem acima ?

Comment: Tentou listar todos os produtos e ordernar, conforme os criterios?

Comment: Não, mas pensei na possibilidade de usar um foreach() para me ajudar. Só que queria ver se tem como fazer direto no comando SQL

Comment: Coloca a estrutura da tabela

Comment: status = 1 (disponivel) / 0 (indisponivel)
foto = '' (sem foto) / 'imagem.png' (com foto)

Comment: Order by status desc , case when foto is null then 0 else 1 end)

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer utilizando somente o `ORDER BY` do MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_produto`
ORDER BY `status` DESC, LENGTH(`foto`) > 0 DESC;
```

Ao utilizar a função `LENGTH()` os valores `''` (vazio) e `NULL` para foto serão exibidos por último.